# Qual a forma mais eficaz de desenvolver um código html5 ou js?

Tags: javascript, html5, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Por exemplo quando quero fazer um evento no click do botão posso fazer de duas maneiras:

utilizando o atributo onclick do html5 `<button type='button' onclick='myFunction()' id='btn0'>O</button>`

ou pelo js :

```
$('#btn0').click(function(){

    myFunction();

});
```

existem situações que ocorrem o uso das duas maneiras como por exemplo:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()" onclick="alert('click event occured')">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
}
</script>
```

É bom essa mesclagem?
Qual a maneira certa na hora de desenvolver e porque?, qual a diferença de usar um ou outro? se possível quais as vantagens e desvantagens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O correto seria comparar funções nativas exemplo...

- `onclick` direto no HTML
- `onclick` no javascript
- `attachEvent`
- `addEventListener`

*O jquery provavelmente implementa addEventListener e attachEvent...*

**Onclick direto no HTML** é algo pouco usado hoje em dia mas surte efeito normalmente.

**Onclick no javascript** é mais comum e fácil de organizar o escopo.

**AttachEvent** Para IE com versões menores a 9.

**AddEventListener** Para IE 9 e versões acima, é amplamente adotado no desenvolvimento javascript.

Em relação a mesclagem, creio que se trata de um [POG](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Orientada_a_Gambiarras)

Em termos de desempenho, se existir diferença é quase que imperceptível...